# Dynamic update of select depending on radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

Im trying to get a dynamic update of my select list depending on what radio button is checked.

I have 3 files:

maleweight.html:

```
<option value="blank"></option> 
<option value="Pluma -64.0 kg">Pluma -64.0 kg</option>
<option value="Pena -70.0 kg">Pena -70.0 kg</option>
<option value="Leve - 76.0 kg">Leve - 76.0 kg</option>
<option value="Médio -82.3 kg">Médio -82.3 kg</option>
<option value="Meio-Pesado -88.3 kg">Meio-Pesado -88.3 kg</option>      
<option value="Pesado -94.3 kg">Pesado -94.3 kg</option>        
<option value="Super Pesado -100.5 kg">Super Pesado -100.5 kg</option>      
<option value="Pesadíssimo +100.5 kg">Pesadíssimo +100.5 kg</option>
```

femaleweight.html:

```
<option value="blank"></option> 
<option value="Rooster -48.5 kg">Rooster -48.5 kg</option>
<option value="Super Feather -53.5 kg">Super Feather -53.5 kg</option>
<option value="Feather -58.5 kg">Feather -58.5 kg</option>
<option value="Light - 64.0 kg">Light - 64.0 kg</option>
<option value="Middle -69.0 kg">Middle -69.0 kg</option>
<option value="Medium Heavy -74.0 kg">Medium Heavy -74.0 kg</option>        
<option value="Heavy -79.3 kg">Heavy -79.3 kg</option>      
<option value="Super Heavy -84.3 kg">Super Heavy -84.3 kg</option>      
<option value="S. Super Heavy +84.3 kg">S. Super Heavy +84.3 kg</option>
```

newuser.php:

```
    <tr>
    <td><b>K&oslash;n:</b></td>

    <td><input type="radio" name="Mand" value="Mand" id="male" onclick="update()">Mand
    <input type="radio" name="Kvinde" value="Kvinde" id="female" onclick="update()">Kvinde</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b>V&aelig;gt:</b></td>
    <td><select id="weight" name="vægt" id="selectv">               
    <script language="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js">

        function update() {

            if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
                $("#weight").load("maleweight.html");
            }

            else if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
                $("#weight").load("femaleweight.html");
            }
        }

    </script>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
```

I have 2 problems:

1. The radio buttons seem broken, i can choose both at the same time and i can not "uncheck" them. - Maybe because of the script not workind properly?
2. When i click either of the radio buttons the select list is not updated.

I have tried:

- Including (just naming the file ex: maleweight.php).
- Javascript (could not make it work).
- .get instead of load.
- Tried .checked == true
- Tried different solutions (not for the exactly same) listed here on SO.

Niether of them will work for me. What am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Casper

EDIT:

The page where everything is going down: http://www.casperwmn.dk/tiljonas/nyprofil.php

Comment: change type from radio to checkbox

Comment: If you give the radio buttons the same name, you will only be able to select one of them.

Comment: Changing type to checkbox dosent help. And i have the possibility of having both checked and not only one. 

Thanks Christofer, the different name thing was while i tried another solution, just missed to rename them again! :-) 
The list wont update still though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few obvious problems with your code.

1. You should use the same name for both radio buttons, if you want to make sure only of one them can be selected.
2. You shouldn't put the JavaScript within your select-element. As soon as the the first `.load()` method completes, it will remove the entire JavaScript as it replaces the content of your select-element. I'm also fairly certain that it is invalid HTML to do so (a `<select>` element can only have `<option>` elements as children).
3. You cannot both load an external JavaScript-file and write your own JavaScript with the same `<script>` tag, you will have to have two separate `<script>` tags - one for loading the jQuery source, and one for writing your own JavaScript.
4. Your `<select>` element has two ID attributes, which isn't valid HTML. Remove one of them, and use the one you keep as the selector in your JavaScript.
5. `<script language="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js">`
    is not the right way to load a JavaScript. Instead of `language="text/javascript"` it should be `type="text/javascript"`, but you could just as well get rid of the attribute all together, as JavaScript is the default language for the `<script>` element.

Since you are using jQuery to load the content, why not use it for the complete solution? If you change the name of your radio-buttons to say `gender`, and the values to male/female, and remove the inline onlick-attribute. Then you could do it all with a small piece of jQuery.

```
$(function() {
   $("input[name='gender']").on("click", function() {
        var gender = $(this).val();
        $("#weight").load(gender + "weight.html");
   });
});
```

Comment: Just moved it inside <head>, yet it is still not updating :-/

Comment: Tried you suggested code, yet the list still wont update for me :-( I have edited in a link in the bottom of my post where the code is up if you need to see it all.

Comment: @Evilunclebill You get a JS-error on your page `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, which indicates that you don't load jQuery properly. I added another point to the list (5), that explain why jQuery doesn't get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> The radio buttons seem broken, i can choose both at the same time and i can not "uncheck" them. - Maybe because of the script not workind properly?

You have to assign them the same `name` attribute. This puts them in the same group so that they can't be selected simultaneously.

> When i click either of the radio buttons the select list is not updated.

Move the script block inside `<head>`.

Also, you can't put js inside a `<script>` tag with `src` attribute. You must use a new `<script>` tag.

And, your `<select>` has 2 `id`s. Although it doesn't get in the way, it is not recommended to do so.

Comment: Removed second id and tried your suggested, yet still not working :-/

Answer (score 0):

Separate jquery include and your script, and move your script in head tag:

```
<script language="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js">     </script>
<script>
    function update() {

        if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
            $("#weight").load("maleweight.html");
        }

        else if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
            $("#weight").load("femaleweight.html");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Name attribute of your tags should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools:

> When a user clicks on a radio-button, it becomes checked, and all
>   other radio-buttons with equal name become unchecked.

You should change radiobuttons name attributes so they have the same name.

Comment: Thank you TwiNight :-) I didn't know it's like that.